# How did the encyclopedia salesman get into the building in S04E03?

Tags: friends

As far as I know and have watched in F.R.I.E.N.D.S, the apartments in the building have a buzzer to let people into the building. So how did the encyclopedia salesman get in in S04E03? Is it to be assumed that someone else in the building buzzed him in?

Comment: A buzzer is no defense for [tailgating or piggybacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piggybacking_(security)).

Comment: I agree. However from what I've watched, I've never noticed such piggybackers if i may put it so; shown in the building. That's what spikes my curiosity.

Comment: Not important to most plots, hence no need to show it.

Comment: What does F.R.I.E.N.D.S. stand for?

Comment: Fabulous Roommates Interacting Everyway, Necessarily Dating Selves

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Door left open.

Door left unlocked.

Someone opened it for him.

He walked in behind someone.

He buzzed someone else and they let him up.

He went up with someone, then decided to go around the building when done.

He lied when he buzzed someone else.

He lives in the building.

Take your pick. It's unimportant to the plot.